# Post to my twitter account

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to post a message to my twitter account.

Most examples I've seen revolve around oauth and logging in as user. I just want to pass in my access code and post.

When I go to the twitter oauth page to generate a curl post request it says:

> Important: This will only be valid for a few minutes. Also remember
>   the cURL command will actually execute the request.

How do I get a request that will always work?

Comment: No matter what, you will always have to grab the OAuth tokens via authentication and then that will give you access to their REST API where you can post to your account.

Answer (score 0):

In the OAuth authentication parameters, there is a timestamp called `oauth_timestamp` which gives a date to your request (number of seconds since the 1/1/1970). It is one of the 2 main parameters (with `oauth_nonce`, a kind of UUID) which identifies your request on the Twitter side. If the `oauth_timestamp` is too old or corresponds to a date in the future, Twitter will consider your request as invalid. For further details, see the corresponding page in the Twitter Documentation : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request

As a consequence there is no way to do a request which will always work.